# Finding the largest number in an array

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I'm trying to figure how to find the largest number in an array of random numbers.

So far I cant manage to get it right.

Its an `array[50]` and the random, numbers are between `0-100`.

Thanks!

Comment: `So far I cant manage to get it right.` Then what are you getting wrong?

Comment: Conceptually, how would you do find the largest number in an array (list, or set)?

Comment: Thats the problem , I cant find the logic to startt , beside etting the random numbers , and the length of the array , I'm pretty much blacked out.

Comment: Say you had ten balls of the same size, but of different weights. What would you do to find the heaviest?

Comment: This has already been answered on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/1806830/265877

Comment: I'll weight each one and compare them to find the heaviest. Edit: thanks alex

Comment: So using that analogy with arrays, how would you get the _weight_ (the value) of each element? How would you compare it?

Comment: sort the array in ascending order and get the last element.

Answer (score 7):

Loop through the array and keep track of the largest number found already in an int variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int findMax(int[] numbers)
{
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
        if (numbers[i] > max) max = numbers[i];

    return max;
}
```

(You can also initialize `max` to `int.MIN_VALUE` or something if it helps behave more suitably in the case where an empty array is passed in.)

Comment: Would the downvoter please comment? Thanks.

Comment: You've deprived the OP of any learning opportunity. Better would be to help the OP arrive at this solution himself.

Comment: @dnault Learning opportunities are up to him, not me. Personally I find studying example code extremely useful and informative when I'm trying to learn something new. If he just pastes in the answer and moves on, he made that choice, not me.

Comment: Fair point about learning from example code. Please have your vote back along with my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
java.utils.Arrays.sort(yours_array);
int largest = yours_array[yours_array.length - 1] ;
```

Comment: @user2966293 don't do this. see my comments in Hammam's solution as to why.  This is essentially the same thing.

Comment: and since Hammam deleted his answer, I'll post it here.  It's inefficient, it modifies the original array.

Answer (score 0):

[Collections.max](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Collections.html) and you can use it as follows with a raw array:

```
List<Integer> triedArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayUtils.addAll(intArray);
```

This does add a dependency on [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `int[]` is named `array`

Try to use a loop like the following:

```
int biggest = array[0]
for(int a = 1; a < array.length; a++){
    if(array[a] > biggest){
        biggest = array[a]
    }
}
```

At the end, your variable biggest will hold the largest value in the array.