# Keeping track of most frequently occuring element in an array of doubles

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

Lets say I have an array of doubles like

[1.2, 1.2, 3.0, 2.7, 1.2]

How would I go about implementing a method that would return the most frequently occurring element's frequency? In this case I just want to make a method that returns 3 for the double 1.2.

Comment: With a `HashMap<Double, Integer>`, key is value of double, value is number of occurances. You should be able to work out the actual loop through the array by yourself.

Comment: The first step would be to make an effort and show us what it was and what didn't work about it.

Comment: I think I know how code a frequency counter using a HashMap for each element, but how would I check which element is the most frequently occurring?

Comment: The hashMap element with the highest value is the most occuring. Look at this article, should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806816/java-finding-the-highest-value-in-an-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a naive approach which should do the trick:

```
public static int mostOccurances(double[] input) {
    Map<Double, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    // Go over the input and store in map
    for (double d : input) {
        Integer count = map.get(d);
        if (count == null) {
            map.put (d, 1);
        } else {
            map.put (d, count + 1);
        }
    }

    // Go over the map and return the maximum occurrence
    // assumption: if input is empty, it's OK to return 0
    int retVal = 0;
    for (int count : map.values()) {
        retVal = Math.max(retVal, count);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```