# Given an array of ints, which is larger between the first and last elements in the array. Return the new array

Tags: java, arrays, element

In this problem I need to find the largest element between the first and the last element in the array, and set all the other elements in that array to be that value and return the new array. My problem is that it works only in arrays of 3 elements. I need to find a way to have it working for any given aaray length. This is what I have so far:

```
public int[] maxEnd(int[] a) {
     if (a[a.length-1] > a[0]) {
         a[0] = a[a.length-1];
         a[1] = a[a.length-1];
     } else {
         a[1] = a[0];
         a[a.length-1] = a[0];
     }
     return a;

}
```

Comment: Your problem states you need to update the whole array. But you are updating only 3 indexes? Update the whole array (in a loop).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806816/java-finding-the-highest-value-in-an-array

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test this cos I'm on mobile, hopefully it works.

```
public int[] maxEnd(int[] array){
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println(array[array.length - 1]);
        int [] results = new int[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            results[i] = array[array.length - 1];
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
public int[] maxEnd(int[] a) {
     if (a[a.length-1] > a[0]) {
         for(int i=0; i < a.length-1; i++){
             a[i] = a[a.length-1];
         }
     } else {
         for(int i=1; i < a.length; i++){
             a[i] = a[0];
         }
     }
     return a;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two lines of code:

```
public int[] naxEnd(int[] a) {
    final int largest = a[a.length-1] > a[0] ? a[a.length-1] : a[0];
    Arrays.fill(a, largest);
}
```

The first line is Java's *conditional operator*, which is described in detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25). Calling `Arrays.fill(a, largest)` has exactly the same effect as writing this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    a[i] = largest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only check which is larger between the first and last element of an array, `Math.max()` can check that for you.  Then use `Arrays.fill()` to replace every element with the max value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxEnd(new int[0])));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxEnd(new int[] {6})));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxEnd(new int[] {38, 73})));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxEnd(new int[] {6, 4, 2, 3, 5, 7})));
}

public static int[] maxEnd(int[] a) {
    if (a.length < 2) {
        return a;
    }

    Arrays.fill(a, Math.max(a[0], a[a.length - 1]));
    return a;
}
```

Results:

```
[]
[6]
[73, 73]
[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```