# How do I select the max value from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a elementary math tutorial, and for this portion I have an array, the array is filled with 5 random numbers, between 0 and 9. The question I am creating would give 5 random digits, and say "What is the highest number that you could make with these digits?", and then I store that number in a variable

```
    // These are all Random numbers using the Random method
    a = num.nextInt(9);
    b = num.nextInt(9);
    c = num.nextInt(9);
    d = num.nextInt(9);
    e = num.nextInt(9);
    f = num.nextInt(9);

    // Asks the question right here (not important right now)
    // prints out 5 digits here (again, not important right now)

    g = ans.nextInt(); // this is the users response 

    int h3[] = {a, b, c, d, e, f}; // this array holds the random numbers
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806816/java-finding-the-highest-value-in-an-array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    Arrays.sort(h3);
    int maxNo = h3[h3.length-1].
```

This should do what you require. Your highest value will be set to maxNo. Dont forget to import Java.util.*;

Answer (score 2):

In java8

```
 IntStream.of(h3).max().getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array in descending order. The number would be the highest 5 digit number.

Although you asked for 5 random numbers but you are filling with six random numbers. Please correct that also.

> int h3[] = {a, b, c, d, e, f};

Comment: Kid. The point is I don't know the descending order because it's a random number. I apologize for not being able to count, but I think that knowing your minuscule amounts of java, you can figure it out. HAND

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could think of doing this would be to make an `int` variable and loop through the array, and if the number is bigger than what is in the int variable, overwrite it.

```
int biggest = -1; //you want this to be negative one originally to ensure it is overwritten

for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i] > biggest) {
        biggest = num[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the currently accepted answer is that it sorts the array. This *may* impact performance if the array of ints is very large. The array doesn't have to be sorted.

Just iterate over the array and store the highest number:

```java
int highest = array[0];
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > highest) {
        highest = array[i];
    }
}
```

Or store the index of the highest number instead:

```java
int indexOfHighest = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > array[indexOfHighest]) {
        indexOfHighest = i;
    }
}
```

You could also use Java Streams:

```java
return IntStream.of(array).max().getAsInt();
```

Of course, all of these snippets assume that the array contains at least one element.