# My method is not properly comparing items in an arrayList to give me the max value - only returns index(0)

Tags: java, class, arraylist, methods

I cannot figure out why this method only returns index(0) and does not cycle through the arraylist to compare the other elements...thoughts?

```
public Shipment getLargest() {

    //Set variable to equal a largest element
    Shipment largest = (Shipment)shipmentList.get(0);

    //Loops through and compares Shipment element values
    for(int i=0; i<shipmentList.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if((shipmentList.get(i)).equals(largest))
        largest = shipmentList.get(i);

    }
    //Returns largest Shipment element
    return  largest;    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop length is not correct. Remove the -1 from the for condition. While `i` is smaller than size, it will reach the last element (size-1)

```
for(int i=0; i<shipmentList.size(); i++)
```

Also, you are comparing the "largest" value with an equals, when you should be checking if the previous "largest" is greater than the current one.

Comment: you need a method on Shipment which compares them for which is "larger".  For example:  if((shipmentList.get(i)).isLarger(largest)) - how that works is up to you, based on what values are in Shipment and what makes one larger than the other

Comment: here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806816/java-finding-the-highest-value-in-an-array

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to work the .isLarger method...I made an enum class of sports goods ("BAT", $15,00) ("GLOVE", 5.99) and now what to compare all those objects (ie. BAT would be most value)