# Optimal algorithm for finding max value

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I need to design an algorithm to find the maximum value I can get from (stepping) along an int[] at predefined (step lengths).

Input is the number of times we can "use" each step length; and is given by n2, n5 and n10. n2 means that we move 2 spots in the array, n5 means 5 spots and n10 means 10 spots. We can only move forward (from left to right).

The int[] contains the values 1..5, the size of the array is (n2*2 + n5*5 + n10*10). The starting point is int[0].

Example: we start at int[0]. From here we can move to int[0+2] == 3, int[0+5] == 4 or int[0+10] == 1. Let's move to int[5] since it has the highest value. From int[5] we can move to int[5+2], int[5+5] or int[5+10] etc.

We should move along the array in step lengths of 2, 5 or 10 (and we can only use each step length n2-, n5- and n10-times) in such a manner that we step in the array to collect as high sum as possible.

The output is the maximum value possible.

```
public class Main {

private static int n2 = 5;
private static int n5 = 3;
private static int n10 = 2;
private static final int[] pokestops = new int[n2 * 2 + n5 * 5 + n10 * 10];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < pokestops.length; i++) {
        pokestops[i] = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 5) + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pokestops));
    //TODO: return the maximum value possible
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a concrete example. The question is not clear.

Comment: As mentioned, an example of how the algorithm must work will help us understand what you need. In the meantime, it appears that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806816/java-finding-the-highest-value-in-an-array) about finding the max value in an array will be of use.

Comment: also there is a mistake in your code since your mentioned size and size in code is different ie n10 * 4 instead of n10 * 10

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added an example and fixed the bug mentioned by @Arthas

Comment: Is it possible to move backwards in the array?

Comment: So just to be clear, given an array, you're trying to find the optimal sequence of intervals (2's, 5's, and 10's) that lead to the maximum possible sum?

Comment: @JasonC exactly! Except we can only move in the interval of 2's n2 times, 5's n5 times and 10's n10 times.

Comment: @JasonC the values in the int[] array are 1..5 (between 1 and 5).

Comment: What's a typical length of the int[] array?

Comment: Also are you allowed to count the same int more than once?

Comment: @JasonC it's supposed to work asymptotically (for an extremely long int[] array). I am allowed to count the same int more than once. I would prefer a polynomial solution if possible.

Comment: Do you wrap around the array if you went from 0 to -2?

Comment: @TadijaBagarić you can start at the end of the array but we can never move from int[7] to int[5] for example.

Comment: @Pavel sorry I don't understand your question. Sorry if I was unclear about backwards earlier. We can not move backwards only forward.

Comment: @Peonsson, okay, then never mind.

Comment: @Pavel or do you mean if the array is a "circle"? it is not.

Comment: @Peonsson what I was asking had to do with going backwards.

Comment: I will try to come up with something later, because as fun as this sounds I'm on my way out the door; but here are my current thoughts in case they inspire anybody: One way of looking at this is a tree of indices where each node has up to 6 branches (+/-2, +/-5, +/-10). Then it becomes a problem of finding the path through the tree with the maximum sum. Optimizations, then, include: Giving up on paths where `5 * remaining_depth < max_sum - current_sum` (since 5*depth is upper bound on sum you can prune paths that you know *can't*  improve), as well as caching sums in equivalent subtrees.

Comment: Well, or up to 3 branches (+2, +5, +10), since now it seems you can't go backwards (for future reference, when somebody asks "Is it possible to move backwards in the array?" and you respond "Yes." but mean "No.", apologizing for being "unclear" later is an understatement, lol -- As interesting as this question is, if you keep leaving key details out that cause well-meaning folks to spend time going down the wrong path, this question should probably be put on hold.)

Comment: @JasonC sorry but I misunderstood the question I didn't change my mind.

Comment: Re: My previous comment about the tree; if you can obtain a copy of http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2296589.2296805, it seems they present a relevant algorithm that can find a maximum-sum path, which can work if you express your tree as a connected acyclic graph with edge length = the int value. They claim O(nlog^2n), although *n* is the total number of nodes, which unfortunately is large and at least exponential in your case (I don't remember the math off the top of my head to calculate total nodes given your array length, n2, n5, n10, but I'm sure it's not too hard to work out).

Comment: @JasonC I added the starting point and that we should always move forward (from left to right). Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer in pseudocode (I didn't run it, but it should work).

```
fill dp with -1.

dp(int id, int 2stepcount, int 5stepcount, int 10stepcount) {
  if(id > array_length - 1) return 0;
  if(dp[id][2stepcount][5stepcount][10stepcount] != -1) return dp[id][2stepcount][5stepcount][10stepcount];
  else dp[id][2stepcount][5stepcount][10stepcount] = 0;
  int 2step = 2stepcount < max2stepcount? dp(id + 2, 2stepcount + 1, 5stepcount, 10stepcount) : 0;
  int 5step = 5stepcount < max5stepcount? dp(id + 5, 2stepcount, 5stepcount + 1, 10stepcount) : 0;
  int 10step = 10stepcount < max10stepcount? dp(id + 10, 2stepcount, 5stepcount, 10stepcount + 1) : 0;
  dp[id][2stepcount][5stepcount][10stepcount] += array[id] + max(2step, 5step, 10step);
  return dp[id][2stepcount][5stepcount][10stepcount];
}
```

Call dp(0,0,0,0) and the answer is in dp[0][0][0][0].

If you wanna go backwards, then you do this:

```
fill dp with -1.

dp(int id, int 2stepcount, int 5stepcount, int 10stepcount) {
  if(id > array_length - 1 || id < 0) return 0;

  if(dp[id][2stepcount][5stepcount][10stepcount] != -1) return dp[id][2stepcount][5stepcount][10stepcount];
  else dp[id][2stepcount][5stepcount][10stepcount] = 0;

  int 2stepForward = 2stepcount < max2stepcount? dp(id + 2, 2stepcount + 1, 5stepcount, 10stepcount) : 0;
  int 5stepForward = 5stepcount < max5stepcount? dp(id + 5, 2stepcount, 5stepcount + 1, 10stepcount) : 0;
  int 10stepForward = 10stepcount < max10stepcount? dp(id + 10, 2stepcount, 5stepcount, 10stepcount + 1) : 0;

  int 2stepBackward = 2stepcount < max2stepcount? dp(id - 2, 2stepcount + 1, 5stepcount, 10stepcount) : 0;
  int 5stepBackward = 5stepcount < max5stepcount? dp(id - 5, 2stepcount, 5stepcount + 1, 10stepcount) : 0;
  int 10stepBackward = 10stepcount < max10stepcount? dp(id - 10, 2stepcount, 5stepcount, 10stepcount + 1) : 0;

  dp[id][2stepcount][5stepcount][10stepcount] += array[id] + max(2stepForward, 5stepForward, 10stepForward, 2stepBackward, 5backForward, 10backForward);
  return dp[id][2stepcount][5stepcount][10stepcount];
}
```

But your paths don't get fulled explored, because we stop if the index is negative or greater than the array size - 1, you can add the wrap around functionality, I guess.

Comment: That does not restrict the number of steps.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, I missed that part of the question.

Comment: That can be fixed by adding parameters that count the number of allowed steps remaining. That will explode the number of values to memoize.

Comment: Yep, recursion is the way to go

Comment: Are you sure this works... ? Each of those calls to `dp()` modifies `dp[]` in a way that isn't convincing... I'm open-minded, but skeptical. I think a good recursive solution could benefit from a proper proof along-side it, if only for a clear explanation.

Comment: (Also the OP says in [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776171/optimal-algorithm-for-finding-max-value?noredirect=1#comment66849122_39776171) that it's possible to move backwards.)

Comment: @JasonC okay, i will modify to be able to go backwards.

Comment: Ok, the OP now [changed their mind about moving backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776171/optimal-algorithm-for-finding-max-value?noredirect=1#comment66849969_39776171)...

Comment: Change the naming... identifiers can only start with letters (including unicode) or `_`, not with a number.

Comment: The question is about Java, clearly. Your answer doesn't state it's pseudo-code, I think I'm right to expect Java code from the answers.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire okay, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

this is a solution but i am not sure how optimal it is !

i did some optimization on it but i think much more can be done

I posted it with the example written in question

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class FindMax {


private static int n2 = 5;
private static int n5 = 3;
private static int n10 = 2;
private static final int[] pokestops = new int[n2 * 2 + n5 * 5 + n10 * 10];


public static int findMaxValue(int n2, int n5, int n10, int pos, int[] pokestops) {
    System.out.print("|");
    if (n2 <= 0 || n5 <= 0 || n10 <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int first;
    int second;
    int third;
    if (pokestops[pos] == 5 || ((first = findMaxValue(n2 - 1, n5, n10, pos + 2, pokestops)) == 5) || ((second = findMaxValue(n2, n5 - 1, n10, pos + 5, pokestops)) == 5) || ((third = findMaxValue(n2, n5, n10 - 1, pos + 10, pokestops)) == 5)) {
        return 5;
    }
    return Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(first, second), third), pokestops[pos]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < pokestops.length; i++) {
        pokestops[i] = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 5) + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pokestops));
    //TODO: return the maximum value possible
    int max = findMaxValue(n2, n5, n10, 0, pokestops);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Max is :" + max);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate following dynamic programming dp[c2][c5][c10][id] - where c2 is number of times you've stepped by 2, c5 - by 5, c10 - by 10 and id - where is your current position. I will write example for c2 and c5 only, it can be easily extended.

```
int[][][][] dp = new int[n2 + 1][n5 + 1][pokestops.length + 1];
for (int[][][] dp2 : dp) for (int[][] dp3 : dp2) Arrays.fill(dp3, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
dp[0][0][0] = pokestops[0];
for (int c2 = 0; c2 <= n2; c2++) {
  for (int c5 = 0; c5 <= n5; c5++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pokestops.length; i++) {
      if (c2 < n2 && dp[c2 + 1][c5][i + 2] < dp[c2][c5][i] + pokestops[i + 2]) {
        dp[c2 + 1][c5][i + 2] = dp[c2][c5][i] + pokestops[i + 2];
      }  
      if (c5 < n5 && dp[c2][c5 + 1][i + 5] < dp[c2][c5][i] + pokestops[i + 5]) {
        dp[c2][c5 + 1][i + 5] = dp[c2][c5][i] + pokestops[i + 5];
      }  
    }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the target language is java, but I like pyhton and conversion will not be complicated.
You can define a 4-dimensional array **dp** where **dp[i][a][b][c]** is the maximum value that you can
get starting in position **i** when you already has **a** steps of length **2**, **b** of length **5** and **c** of length
**10**. I use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to get a cleaner code.

```
import random

values = []
memo = {}

def dp(pos, n2, n5, n10):
    state = (pos, n2, n5, n10)
    if state in memo:
        return memo[state]
    res = values[pos]
    if pos + 2 < len(values) and n2 > 0:
        res = max(res, values[pos] + dp(pos + 2, n2 - 1, n5, n10))
    if pos + 5 < len(values) and n5 > 0:
        res = max(res, values[pos] + dp(pos + 5, n2, n5 - 1, n10))
    if pos + 10 < len(values) and n10 > 0:
        res = max(res, values[pos] + dp(pos + 10, n2, n5, n10 - 1))
    memo[state] = res
    return res

n2, n5, n10 = 5, 3, 2

values = [random.randint(1, 5) for _ in range(n2*2 + n5*5 + n10*10)]

print dp(0, n2, n5, n10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suspiciously like homework. Not tested:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    private static Step[] steps = new Step[]{
            new Step(2, 5),
            new Step(5, 3),
            new Step(10, 2)
    };

    private static final int[] pokestops = new int[calcLength(steps)];

    private static int calcLength(Step[] steps) {
        int total = 0;
        for (Step step : steps) {
            total += step.maxCount * step.size;
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < pokestops.length; i++) {
            pokestops[i] = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 5) + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pokestops));

        int[] initialCounts = new int[steps.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
            initialCounts[i] = steps[i].maxCount;
        }

        Counts counts = new Counts(initialCounts);
        Tree base = new Tree(0, null, counts);
        System.out.println(Tree.max.currentTotal);

    }


    static class Tree {
        final int pos;
        final Tree parent;
        private final int currentTotal;

        static Tree max = null;

        Tree[] children = new Tree[steps.length*2];
        public Tree(int pos, Tree parent, Counts counts) {
            this.pos = pos;
            this.parent = parent;
            if (pos < 0 || pos >= pokestops.length || counts.exceeded()) {
                currentTotal = -1;
            } else {
                int tmp = parent == null ? 0 : parent.currentTotal;
                this.currentTotal = tmp + pokestops[pos];
                if (max == null || max.currentTotal < currentTotal) max = this;
                for (int i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
                    children[i] = new Tree(pos + steps[i].size, this, counts.decrement(i));
                    // uncomment to allow forward-back traversal:
                    //children[2*i] = new Tree(pos - steps[i].size, this, counts.decrement(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class Counts {
        int[] counts;

        public Counts(int[] counts) {
            int[] tmp = new int[counts.length];
            System.arraycopy(counts, 0, tmp, 0, counts.length);
            this.counts = tmp;
        }

        public Counts decrement(int i) {
            int[] tmp = new int[counts.length];
            System.arraycopy(counts, 0, tmp, 0, counts.length);
            tmp[i] -= 1;
            return new Counts(tmp);
        }

        public boolean exceeded() {
            for (int count : counts) {
                if (count < 0) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    static class Step {
        int size;
        int maxCount;

        public Step(int size, int maxCount) {
            this.size = size;
            this.maxCount = maxCount;
        }
    }
}
```

There's a line you can uncomment to allow forward and back movement (I'm sure someone said in the comments that was allowed, but now I see in your post it says forward only...)