# How to sort integers in Java and save in some TextViews

Tags: java, android

I need to compare 9 Integers to find out which is bigger, and i need the bigger to be in the first textview the second bigger integer to be in the second textview and so on.

The integers are collected by another activity

```
 //All the integers are not constant the numbers is just for the example

 integer1 = 10
 integer2 = 4
 integer3 = 13
 integer4 = 21 
 integer5 = 20
 integer6 = 2
 integer7 = 32
 integer8 = 100
 integer9 = 23

 //Heres the textviews
    WinnerTextView = findViewById(R.id.WinnerTextView);
    SecondTextView = findViewById(R.id.SecondTextView);
    ThirdTextView = findViewById(R.id.ThirdTextView);
    ForthTextView = findViewById(R.id.ForthTextView);
    FifthTextView = findViewById(R.id.FifthTextView);
    SixthTextView = findViewById(R.id.SixthTextView);
    SeventhTextView = findViewById(R.id.SeventhTextView);
    EigthTextView = findViewById(R.id.EighthTextView);
    NinthTextView =  findViewById(R.id.NinthTextView);
```

I tried with if, but its gonna take like 1000 lines of code.

Comment: 1) Put the numbers into an array. 2) Sort the array 3) Loop the array to set text view values. Takes like 3 lines of code, you just have to try ;)

Comment: Add the numbers in arraylist. Use  Collections.sort(arraylist); Access the number based on index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Finding the highest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806816/java-finding-the-highest-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I suggest you to use a `RecyclerView` instead of that.

But if you don't want to use `RecyclerView`:
I don't really suggest using a list at all. You wont need it. Just use a java `int[]` which is an array of integers.

Example:

```
int[] numbers = {10, 4, 13 , 21, 20, 2, 32, 100 , 23};

Arrays.sort(numbers);
//now numbers are sorted in ascending order

textViewNumber1.setText(String.valueOf(numbers[8]) //your first element is at index 0
textViewNumber2.setText(String.valueOf(numbers[7])) 
.... and so on so forth
```

Comment: what is the recyclerview for then?

Comment: my bad on the sentence, fixed it

Comment: question remains, why are you suggesting a RV? What for?

Comment: think about it, 9 textviews? He can just have an adapter and a list of 9 elements sorted.

Comment: then explain that in the answer. Someone who asks this kind of question most certainly would not know why to use a recyclerview, much less how to

Comment: I'm assuming he knows what a `RecyclerView` is, I gave him the answer, if he wants to use RV and doesn't know, he can ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> items=new ArrayList<>();
// Add your integers in an Arraylist. 
items.add(integer1);
items.add(integer2);
....
....
items.add(integer9);

// Sort them in reverse order, so that bigger number comes first.
Arrays.sort(items, Collections.reverseOrder());

// Assign them to your Textview with index of the arraylist.
WinnerTextView.setText(items.get(0));
SecondTextView.setText(items.get(1));
...
...
NinthTextView.setText(items.get(9));
```

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Can Do something like this

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    al.add("1"); 
    al.add("2"); 
    al.add("3"); 
    al.add("4"); 
    al.add("5"); 

    /* Collections.sort method is sorting the 
    elements of ArrayList in descendingorder. */
    Collections.sort(al, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: that's like 1/3rd of an answer

Answer (score 0):

So you need to have a list of integers from that `Activity`. As previously mentioned.
Simple code would be:

```
List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>();
numList.add(10);
...
numList.add(23);
Collections.sort(numList);
//Reverse so the first one will be the biggest
Collections.reverse(numList);
```

Now you have numbers in correct order so you should somehow bind them to views. For this purpose create another list but it will consist of `TextView`s in desired order

```
List<TextView> txList = new ArrayList<>();
txList.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.WinnerTextView);
...
txList.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.NinthTextView);
```

Using this list you could bind results to text view like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < txList.size() && i < numList.size(); i++) {
    txList.get(i).setText((numList.get(i).toString()));
}
```

I've added additional check so code will work even if you change your mind and increase or decrease range.

The same could be done using iterators like so:

```
Iterator<Integer> nums = numList.iterator();
Iterator<TextView> textViews = txList.iterator();

while(nums.hasNext() && textViews.hasNext()) {
    textViews.next().setText(nums.next().toString());
}
```

And in the end this will solve your current problem but as mentioned in other comments you just need a dedicated view to display a list of items. It could be simple [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView) with [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) or it could be [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) a bit more code to write for this task but is recommended.