# How to find the position of the highest and second highest value in an array in java

Tags: java

Let's assume that we have an array with integer numbers. For Example 
perimeter={180,50,65,78,90,5,150,2,35} and i want to find the highest value and its position in the array and the second value and its position in the array.

```
public class FindTopTwo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double perimeter[]= {180,50,65,78,90,5,150,2,35};
    double megisto, megisto2;
    int i;
    megisto=perimeter[0];
    megisto2=perimeter[0];
    for (i=0;i<perimeter.length;i++) {
        if (perimeter[i]>megisto) {
            megisto2=megisto;
            megisto=perimeter[i];}
        else if (perimeter[i]>megisto2) {
            megisto2=perimeter[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("the first is:"+megisto+"the second highest value is "+megisto2);    

   }

}
```

Comment: What is your question? This is a problem statement and a piece of code. Does the code not work? If not, in what way doesn't it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Finding the highest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806816/java-finding-the-highest-value-in-an-array)

Comment: @AnilM, no. He has clearly indicated that he wants to find two indexes and two values.

Comment: The code works as it finds the highest and next highest value, but there is a gap in finding the position where the maximum and the next maximum value in the array is placed. For example lets assume that we have an array {10, 20, 30,40} the maximum value is 40 and the next highest value is 30. I WANT TO FIND ALSO THE POSITION THAT MEANS "THE POSITION OF 40 is 3 if we assume that array begins with 0 as the first position.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of their indexes(`i`) as their values change:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double perimeter[]= {180,50,65,78,90,5,150,2,35};
    double megisto, megisto2;
    megisto=perimeter[0];
    int megistoIndex = 0;

    megisto2=perimeter[0];

    int megisto2Index = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<perimeter.length;i++) {
        if (perimeter[i]>megisto) {
          megistoIndex = i;
          megisto = perimeter[i];
        } else if (perimeter[i] < megisto && perimeter[i] > megisto2) {
          megisto2Index = i;
          megisto2 = perimeter[i];
        }

    }
    System.out.println(String.format("the first is: %d at index %d. The second highest value is %d at index %d", megisto, megistoIndex, megisto2, megisto2Index));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set highestIndex = -1;
set nextHighestIndex = -1;

for every element of perimiter:

  if highestIndex = -1:
    set highestIndex = i;
  else if perimiter[i] > perimiter[highestIndex]
    set nextHighestIndex = highestIndex;
    set highestIndex = i;
  else if perimiter[i] > perimieter[nextHighestIndex]
    set nextHighestIndex = i;
```

If the array is not empty, you will find the highest value in
    perimiter[highestIndex]

If the array has at least two distinct values, you will find the second highest value in
    perimeter[nextHighestIndex]